windows service using multiple accounts
If I start one windows-service using service-account (SA1) but then in the code of the service if I want to access some external service in network using gMSA or sMSA, is it possible?
Does windows OS allow the  process (application/service) spun with one account and use other account to complete NTLM or Kerberos authentication during network call?
If I want to use MSA, I believe there is NO password required but if I want to use some different user-account how will service received password?

The identity of a running thread is stored in the Thread Token.  You can create tokens using LogonUser and other functions and use that token using SetThreadToken.  WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated is a wrapper which lets you do the "set-run-revert" step easily.  Elastic gives a good overview of how windows tokens work.
Network connections are based on cached credentials.  Impersonation allows for network access, but might not be necessary if there are no local resources and you are not interested in performing ACL checks.  For "network only" access, you can add cached credentials directly using WNetAddConnection* (or a wrapper).  This is similar to running net use ....  Cached credentials can also be used in cases where authentication is not possible (from Workgroup computers or when there is no line of sight to a DC).
As mentioned in your other question about MSA's, MSA's are mostly normal accounts and do have passwords.  The password is stored unencrypted in LDAP and automatically changed from time to time.  The msDS-ManagedPassword attribute is then ACL'd so only certain computers/callers can access it.  To have the system retrieve it automatically during the call to LogonUser, specify SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD then impersonate.  Otherwise retrieve the password by any means, then call WNetAddConnection*.

Thanks @Mitch.  I am still studying your response.
But one think I want ask off the bat is,   it is the duty of my service-code to first retrieve the password of MSA by any means and then use it with one of the APIs provided by Windows OS to make the network-call ??
If this is true then that means service running with any identity can get MSA password using couple of  cmdlets ??

Only an application running as an identity which has been granted access to msDS-ManagedPassword / PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword is allowed to retrieve the password.  After that, yeah.  There's nothing "special" about an MSA.  Step 1 is to acquire a token or the password using a suitably privileged identity, step 2 is to impersonate the token or cache the password, step 3 is to access a resource.

and this is where I have disconnect.
I have actually created a separate question with code at following, if you could respond me there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78953713/getting-managed-service-account-password
