getting Managed service account password

Hello
As shown in above diagram, we know how we can add windows-services and how they are run under a shell of svchost.exe
Let's say I am adding one simple heart-beat service on one AD domain joined windows box.
On this windows box I have already installed one   Managed Service Account.
Now while configuring heart-beat service,  I am running it under a regular user-account.
So I  believe the security-context of this service is around this regular user-account
Is it possible for the code of this service to retrieve the  Managed Service Account  password by something like following
$MSA = ConvertFrom-ADManagedPasswordBlob (Get-ADServiceAccount SvcCustomerWeb -prop 'msDS-ManagedPassword' | Select -expand 'msDS-ManagedPassword')
ConvertTo-NTHash $MSA.SecureCurrentPassword

I understand that if I had run this service under  built-in  SYSTEM account then the code can definitely get the MSA password.  But in this case I am running the service under some regular account who has Log on as Service permission

So @Mitch are you saying that the regular user-account that my service is running under ,  must be with msDS-ManagedPassword/principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword  for above snippet of code to work  ??

Because my impression was that only  computers can be added into principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword

Correct.  Any principal (user / computer / group) can be added to principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword.  Various GUI's will prevent anything but a computer or group from being added.  Note also: NT Services can be any exe - they are not always svchost.  NT Services are normal executables which respond to the SCM.  RunAsService and many other tools will run arbitrary exe's as services.

Also, Log on as a service is a right on the local computer - it is not a network permission.  It does not control whether you can access the password.   Only the ACL of the msDS-ManagedPassword attribute controls that (which you can see with ADSIEdit or Get-Acl.

Thanks Mitch...  So I have one hands-on question .
When you  run "Install-ADServiceAccount"  cmdlet from any windows-server,   would this update the list of  "principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword"  in MSA   and  add  this windows-server in it   ??

You adjust the ACL for the password using Set-ADServiceAccount [-Identity] <string> -PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword <ADPrincipal[]>.

I think Install-ADServiceAccount is a vestige of standalone MSA's and isn't really needed with gMSA's.  It's probably kept around because it is an easy way to grant the local logon right.  (Non-MSA accounts typically receive logon rights via a grant to BUILTIN\Users which includes Domain Users by default).  You can do that via UI (secpol.msc), powershell, secedit, or ntrights.exe).

@Mitch  are you saying that  in any case I have to put the computer under principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword  through   Set-ADServiceAccount  irrespective of  whether I have run  or not run  Install-ADServiceAccount"     ??

Meaning the job of   Install-ADServiceAccount"   is just to do  local-logon-right         I was in impression that this cmdlet will also authorize  this  server  to fetch  password  WITHOUT  putting this server under   principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword        Am I right ?

I think Install-ADServiceAccount/NetAddServiceAccount may have modified standalone MSA's, but not sure.  I don't think it modifes gMSA's.  With gMSA's existing, there's not much point for sMSA's, so I'm not overly familiar with them.  It should not be possible to access the password unless you are running as a principal listed in principalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword.  That might be a computer identity, that might be a user.

I think sMSA's were basically a special "secondary domain join", so NetAddServiceAccount is the "Join" that establishes the trust and creates the AD object, and NetRemoveServiceAccount unjoins.  That's not really relevant to gMSA's, since the password is stored in LDAP - not the LSA.

Ok, let me test it out.
